# multiple datasource with spring boot jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, multiple-databases

Trying to setup dual datasource with spring boot, but it would seem alot harder then first thought,

tried to follow tons of tutorials and guides, but keep getting error with my repos.

application properties

```
# Primary DataSource
datasource.primary.url=url
datasource.primary.username=user
datasource.primary.password=pw
datasource.primary.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

# Secondary DataSource
datasource.secondary.url=url
datasource.secondary.username=user
datasource.secondary.password=pw
datasource.secondary.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

# hibernate strategy (create/update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# name strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

first db config

```
    package com.anders.cphbusiness.db;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
    import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            basePackages = {"com.anders.cphbusiness.repositories"},
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEM")

    public class LoadDataSourceConfig {
        @Bean(name = "primaryDS")
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
        public DataSource loadingDataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primaryPU")
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "primaryEM")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean loadingEntityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("primaryDS") DataSource primaryDS) {
            return builder
                    .dataSource(primaryDS)
                    .persistenceUnit("primaryPU")
                    .packages("com.anders.cphbusiness.entitiesModel")
                    .build();
        }

        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "primaryTM")
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
                @Qualifier("primaryEM") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }

    }
```

second db config

```
package com.anders.cphbusiness.db;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.anders.cphbusiness.secondRepo",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEM",
        transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager")

public class StoreDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "secondaryDS")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource storingDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "secondaryPU")
    @Bean(name = "secondaryEM")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean storingEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("secondaryDS") DataSource secondaryDS) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(secondaryDS)
                .packages("com.anders.cphbusiness.storingModel")
                .persistenceUnit("secondaryPU")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryTM")
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("secondaryEM") EntityManagerFactory secondaryEM) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(secondaryEM);
    }
}
```

repo examples

```
package com.anders.cphbusiness.repositories;

import com.anders.cphbusiness.entitiesModel.WagerBoard;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Repository
@PersistenceContext(name = "primaryEM")
public interface WagerBoardRepo extends JpaRepository<WagerBoard, String> {

}
```

storeDbEntRepo:

```
package com.anders.cphbusiness.secondRepo;

import com.anders.cphbusiness.entitiesModel.WagerBoard;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Repository
@PersistenceContext(name = "secondaryEM")
public interface StoreDbEntRepo extends JpaRepository<WagerBoard, String> {

}
```

the error

```
2017-02-07 10:57:54.222 ERROR 7176 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storeDbEntRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.anders.cphbusiness.entitiesModel.WagerBoard
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.anders.cphbusiness.DsRngCheckerApplication.main(DsRngCheckerApplication.java:18) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.anders.cphbusiness.entitiesModel.WagerBoard
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:152) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:99) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Where is your storeDbEntRepo bean? Can u post it?

Comment: @CletoGadelha added the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is: `not a managed type: class com.anders.cphbusiness.entitiesModel.WagerBoard`

Your StoreDbEntRepo is using "secondaryEM", but is using WagerBoard entity to create the repo.

WagerBoard entity belongs to entitiesModel package. If you want to use that entity into your StoreDbEntRepo, your need to scan the proper package in your EntityManager, doing an update from

```
.packages("com.anders.cphbusiness.storingModel")
```

to

```
.packages("com.anders.cphbusiness.storingModel","com.anders.cphbusiness.entitiesModel").
```

But if your don't, use an entity that belongs to storingModel package to create the StoreDbEntRepo.

Comment: entitiesModel is the entities for primary db and storingModel is for secondary db

Comment: Ok, but you are using the WagerBoard entity into your secondary db.

Comment: If you use another entity of storingModel package into your StoreDbEntRepo, it will work without any change, but to use the WagerBoard entity, you need to scan it.

Comment: not sure what you mean with 'scan it' (im pretty new to spring) 
- the wagerbaord ent is for the primary. the only repo the secondary should use is 'storeDbEntRepo"

Comment: com.anders.cphbusiness.entitiesModel + com.anders.cphbusiness.repositories = first db (primary)

com.anders.cphbusiness.secondRepo.storeDbEntRepo + 
com.anders.cphbusiness.storingModel.storeDbEnt = second db

Comment: So change the entity used to create StoreDbEntRepo. It's simple. The Fact is that you are using an entity from an unscanned package, and that's is your related problem.

Comment: com.anders.cphbusiness.storingModel is the package for the entetity that the repo storedbEntRepo uses. - I dont understand what u mean by " change it " ?

Comment: storedbEntRepo : import com.anders.cphbusiness.entitiesModel.WagerBoard;

Comment: yes, sorry my bad. I Noticed. now i get  No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match! when trying to do a findall

Comment: do i need to do @Transaction before using the repo's ?

Comment: No..maybe your config has some mistakes. Please see the following project for reference: https://github.com/drumonii/SpringBootTwoDataSources